# How convert iterable to bool in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert a iterable to a bool in python?

```py
from itertools import repeat
t = repeat(True)
f = repeat(False)

# Expect True, actual: True.
print(bool(t))

# Expect infinity loop or False,
# actual: True.
print(bool(f))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand whats happening in `itertools.repeat()`. The function returns a generator. So possibily infinite numbers of booleans in your case. To make it easier you can translate that generator into a list.

Lets say [True, False, True]. Now you want to know the bool value associated with that list. But now you have to decide. Do you want to return True if `all()` values are True or only if `any()` value in the list is True? You can do that via `all([True, False, True])`

Ok lets go back to your generator and itertools.reapeat(). Since repeat() always repeats the first value, you essentiall have lists like this [True, True, True]. Therefore you can just ask the generator for the `next()` value because all later values will be the same. Since you already generated a generator of booleans, The value you get returned is already a boolean so no need for `bool()`

```
from itertools import repeat
t = repeat(True)
f = repeat(False)

next(t)
# True
next(f)
# False
```

Comment: Thanks! `any` and `all` is what I need